# searching three different words using regex in python

Tags: python

I am trying to search three different words in the below output

```
+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+
|    radius-server    |           address         |      secret      |  auth-port |  acc-port |  max-retry |  timeout |    nas-ip-local   |  max-out-trans |
+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+
|              rad_11 |                 127.0.0.1 |       testing123 |       9812 |      9813 |          5 |       10 |           disable |            200 |
+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+
```

They are `rad_11`, `127.0.0.1` and `testing123`. Can someone help me out ?

I have tried `re.search ('rad_11' '127.0.0.1' 'testing123', output)`.

Comment: what exactly do you try to accomplish? Do you want to get the possition? or figure out if there is the occurence of your test strings at all? is the order important? or do you just want to "parse" the output, that you have at the end "rad_11", 127.0.0.1 and testing123 in an array?

Comment: Is the output one long string? Looks like a db dump pasted into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can clear all unnecessary symbols and parse the string:

```
import re

new_string = re.sub('\+[\-]*|\n', '', a).strip(' |').replace('||', '|')

names_values = map(lambda x: x.strip(' |\n'), filter(bool, new_string.split(' | ')))

count_of_values = len(names_values)/2
names, values = names_values[:count_of_values], names_values[count_of_values:]
print dict(zip(names, values))

>>> {'max-out-trans': '200', 'nas-ip-local': 'disable', 'address': '127.0.0.1', 
 'radius-server': 'rad_11', 'secret': 'testing123', 'acc-port': '9813', 
 'timeout': '10', 'auth-port': '9812', 'max-retry': '5'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For matching any of the patterns, you can use `re.findall()`:

```
import re
>>> string = "+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+ | radius-server | address | secret | auth-port | acc-port | max-retry | timeout | nas-ip-local | max-out-trans | +---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+ | rad_11 | 127.0.0.1 | testing123 | 9812 | 9813 | 5 | 10 | disable | 200 | +---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+"
>>> print re.findall(r'rad_11|127\.0\.0\.1|testing123', string)
>>> ['rad_11', '127.0.0.1', 'testing123']
```

Searching all patterns is much simpler:

```
def all_exists(string, patterns):
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern not in string:
            return False
    return True

>>> print all_exists('aaa bbb ccc', ['aaa', 'bbb'])
True
>>> print all_exists('aaa bbb ccc', ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd'])
False
```

From `re.findall()`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html);

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group.** Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but will it match all the three words or any word

Comment: Any of the words. What is your requirement? Can you update the question with that?

Comment: i need to search all the three words

Comment: If you require all the words, you can run subsequent regex searches with each of them. What's the challenge?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use :

```
>>> if 'rad_11' in string and '127.0.0.1' in string and 'testing123' in string:
...  print "Got all 3"
... else:
...  print "Failed - all 3 not present"
... 
Got all 3
>>> if 'rad_11' in string and '127.0.0.2' in string and 'testing123' in string:
...  print "Got all 3"
... else:
...  print "Failed - all 3 not present"
... 
Failed - all 3 not present
```

It isn't fancy but it is clear and does the job

Comment: You need to read about *all* and *any*: *if all(value in string for value in ['rad_11', '127.0.0.2', 'testing123']):*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable
I am getting the above error message if i use the code.

Comment: i am using Python2.7.3 version

Comment: @19081982 Are you referring to my answer or the code from JRazor?